# Ask for review on JavaScript code style/structure, usage of patterns, and general quality of the solution

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, on-topic

I have code I want to get reviews for. It's not a particular problem, and the code actually works wonders.

I just want to see what other experts can suggest in order to make it better, improve style, structure, etc.

Is this a suitable question for this site?

Comment: Why are you confused if this is on topic? Was the help unclear?

Answer (score 10):

As long as you can describe what the code is supposed to accomplish, and the code actually works, yes, it's exactly the kind of advice we could provide on Code Review.

Comment: I'm excited, thanks.

Comment: Just posted here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44283/38725